# Testing MS Teams app in a different organization

Tags: testing, bots, microsoft-teams

We've created a teams app and would like to test it within a different organisation as a pilot. We can see 2 ways of doing this, either submitting it to the partner center store or getting the admin within the pilot company to upload the app package themselves (such as in the link below).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/manage-apps?toc=%2Fmicrosoftteams%2Fplatform%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fmicrosoftteams%2Fplatform%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#upload-an-app-package

Does anyone have any recommendations for this or any workarounds? We're unlikely to have the app in a fully finished state (hence the testing) so want to avoid uploading it to the app store for anyone to download. It seems a little strange that there isn't an option to allow pilots more easily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, it has to be put into either the main App store, or to the "company" app store so that users in that tenant can install it. To that end, the options you've listed are pretty much in line, but there are also other ways to get it into the tenant's "company" store. It will depend on their user policy settings though:

- It might be enabled for users to upload apps into the store directly (in the Apps list in Teams on the bottom left there could be a "Upload a custom app" menu option). This is ideal if there are a lot of users who need the app.
- If user side-loading is enabled, the select user(s) could install the "App Studio" app into their own Teams environment, and from there there are steps to open a manifest zip file and install the app personally or to a Team/Chat. If this is an app for a Team/Chat, that would be fine. If it's an app that users need to personally install (e.g. a ['Personal' Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-personal-tab?tabs=nodejs) app) then each user would need to do this - fine for a small number of users, but not great for lots of users.

Comment: sure thing, glad to hear!